# Determining propensity scores with various classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I've read a few papers which consider using classifiers besides logistic regression to determine propensity scores, but none of them explain how exactly to get the propensity scores from the model. Specifically, I'm interested in using J48, Bagging, and AdaBoostM1 (the latter two most likely either with logistic regression or J48). For J48 I was thinking I could just use the probability of that node being classified as yes to determine propensity and for the other two, take the probability from each tree or equation and average them. But I'm wondering if there is a correct way to do this. I have very little statistical background and no ML background. Any good resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Whoo, jargon! I'm gonna sit here and feel smart for knowing a few of those words.On another note, questions asking for a library aren't the kind of thing we look for here on SO -- try Software Recommendations instead.

Comment: I'm not looking for software recommendations. I'm wondering how to turn a classifier into a propensity score. Like I said, I found a lot of references to it, but no actually explanation on how to do it so I assumed it was something simple that no one bothered to explain because it's just one of those things everyone knows. Is there a better place to ask about classifiers/propensity scores?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. It's still outside of the scope of SO, or at least there's a flag reason for "looking for a tutorial". You might want to try Math.SE; I don't really know what propensity scores are so I can't give a better response. Any answers they give you would be language-agnostic so you could port them to whatever.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just a bit frustrated since I'm not sure where to ask this and everywhere I ask seems to be the wrong place.